# OpenCV & C++: returned cv::Mat causes a Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, opencv, basler

I'm writing a class that grabs frames from basler USB cameras using pylonAPI and converts them to openCV format. Here's the code of the grabbing method:

```
std::pair<cv::Mat, cv::Mat> GrabPair()
    {
        int key;
        Pylon::CImageFormatConverter fmtConv;
        Pylon::CPylonImage pylonImg1, pylonImg2;
        fmtConv.OutputPixelFormat = Pylon::PixelType_BGR8packed;
        Pylon::CPylonImage pylonImgLeft, pylonImgRight;

        cv::Mat outImageL, outImageR;
        Pylon::CGrabResultPtr pResultLeft, pResultRight;

        if(cams.IsGrabbing()){
            cams[leftCamIndex].RetrieveResult(1000, pResultLeft, Pylon::TimeoutHandling_ThrowException);    
            cams[rightCamIndex].RetrieveResult(1000, pResultRight, Pylon::TimeoutHandling_ThrowException);  

            if(pResultLeft->GrabSucceeded() && pResultRight->GrabSucceeded()){
                fmtConv.Convert(pylonImgLeft, pResultLeft);
                
                outImageL = cv::Mat(pResultLeft->GetHeight(), 
                    pResultLeft->GetWidth(), 
                    CV_8UC3,
                    (uint8_t*)pylonImgLeft.GetBuffer()
                );

                fmtConv.Convert(pylonImgRight, pResultRight);

                outImageR = cv::Mat(pResultRight->GetHeight(), 
                    pResultRight->GetWidth(), 
                    CV_8UC3,
                    (uint8_t*)pylonImgRight.GetBuffer()
                );

                /*cv::namedWindow("OpenCV out L");
                cv::namedWindow("OpenCV out R");

                cv::imshow("OpenCV out L", outImageL);
                cv::imshow("OpenCV out R", outImageR);
                key = cv::waitKey(20);*/
            }
        }

        return std::make_pair(outImageL, outImageR);                
    }
```

And this is the code fragment from `main()` where I try to acquire and show the grabbed frames

```
int key;
    BslrCap bc(40146142, 40146151); //the grabber object
    bc.PrintDevicesInfo();
    bc.Open();
    cv::Mat raw_left, raw_right;
    while(1)
    {        
        std::pair<cv::Mat, cv::Mat> images_pair = bc.GrabPair();
        cv::Mat raw_left = images_pair.first;
        cv::Mat raw_right = images_pair.second;

        if(!raw_right.empty() && !raw_left.empty()){            
            cv::namedWindow("OpenCV out L");
            cv::namedWindow("OpenCV out R");

            cv::imshow("OpenCV out L", raw_left);
            cv::imshow("OpenCV out R", raw_right);

            key = cv::waitKey(20);
        }
    }
```

But when I call `cv::imshow` I immediately receive SIGSEGV and my program crashes.

If I uncomment these lines in `GrabPair()` code:

```
                    pResultRight->GetWidth(), 
                    CV_8UC3,
                    (uint8_t*)pylonImgRight.GetBuffer()
                );

                /*cv::namedWindow("OpenCV out L");
                cv::namedWindow("OpenCV out R");

                cv::imshow("OpenCV out L", outImageL);
                cv::imshow("OpenCV out R", outImageR);
                key = cv::waitKey(20);*/
```

I can see two openCV windows on my screen with two captured frames. This means that both frames are captured without errors, and the problem is when I try to return std::pair from the method `GrabPair()` back to `main()`

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Great thanks in advance!

Comment: `(uint8_t*)pylonImgLeft.GetBuffer()` This pointer will go out of scope when the function ends.

Comment: ```This means that both frames are captured without errors``` What makes you think this?

Comment: @Raildex I can see two pictures in two openCV named windows, if I uncomment the commented lines in `GrabPair` method. Imshow in `GrabPair` works fine and doesn't causes segmentation fault

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Thanks a lot! Your advice lead me to answer! I've fixed my code so it works correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem here is, that the Mat constructor using an *external pointer* is NOT refcounted. once you leave the `GrabPair` function, both Mat's are invalid (dangling pointer)

you need to clone() them (deep copy of the data !) e.g. like:

```
    return std::make_pair(outImageL.clone(), outImageR.clone());
```

Comment: Thank you! I've found this solution by myself - thanks to @JohnnyMopp advice. But still thank you for your time and help!